# Akka remote configuration issue

Tags: java, scala, akka, akka-cluster

There's something I don't understand about `akka.conf` configuration file when working with Akka actor model (for Java but must be the same for Scala).

For example when using remote module :

I sometimes see something like this :

```
akka {
  actor {
    provider = "akka.remote.RemoteActorRefProvider"
  }
  
  remote {
```

And sometimes :

```
akka {
  actor {
    provider = remote
  }
  
  remote {
```

First whatis the expected value for key `provider` ? Sometimes it is a classname, sometimes it is juste `remote`
By the way, why it is `remote` and not `akka.remote` considering remote is under `akka` namespace ?

Comment: I think the above one was in old implementations, and the provider in the current version can be cluster or remote. It's always better to use akka-cluster rather than remoting. But akka-cluster underlying will use akka-remoting.
Check this link:
https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/remoting-artery.html#configuration

Answer (score 3):

From the [reference.conf](https://github.com/akka/akka/blob/1e9e98472761be93302302e3881a7e7584addc68/akka-actor/src/main/resources/reference.conf) (current at the time of this answer's writing):

```
akka.actor {
  # Either one of "local", "remote" or "cluster" or the
  # FQCN of the ActorRefProvider to be used; the below is the built-in default,
  # note that "remote" and "cluster" requires the akka-remote and akka-cluster
  # artifacts to be on the classpath.
  provider = "local"
```

`akka.actor.provider` is a string which is interpreted on startup.  This interpretation occurs by constructing a `ProviderSelection` (see [here](https://github.com/akka/akka/blob/1e9e98472761be93302302e3881a7e7584addc68/akka-actor/src/main/scala/akka/actor/ActorSystem.scala#L99)).  If a fully-qualified class name is provided, that is used.  `cluster`, `local` (the default, from `reference.conf`), and `remote` are synonyms for `akka.cluster.ClusterActorRefProvider`, `akka.actor.LocalActorRefProvider`, and `akka.remote.RemoteActorRefProvider`, respectively.